# How to print a unsigned char to a human readable format in c?

Tags: c, char

I would like to print the unsigned char in this format:
`0xff`. How can I do so? Thanks.

Comment: Ahem: `printf("%#x\n", 0xFF);` read your documentation answerers.

Comment: @self. Little-known modifier, although I don't understand why. Better than hard-coding `0x`, for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf("0x%x\n", variable);
```

Visit [printf documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) page for more details

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("0x%02X", value & 0xFF);
```

if you want to values to always be 2 characters. also "& 0xFF" will avoid some values to be printed with a lot of "F" in the front (happens sometimes)

Answer (score 1):

`%x` is the basic conversion specifier for printing an `unsigned int` (that's what an `unsigned char` is converted to when passed to a variadic function, such as `printf()`) in hexadecimal format with lowercase letters. If you want leading zeroes and at least two digits, use `%02x`. If, in addition, you want the `0x` prefix as well, prepend the `#` modifier. So your format string will look like

```
"%#02x"
```

Answer (score 0):

%x is the format specifier you are looking for.

```
printf("0x%x\n",your_char);
```

Answer (score 0):

For chars I use this

```
printf("0x%hhx\n",your_char);
```